# Java: How to get address of array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a C++ code to Java.
The C++ code snippet is: `findMedian(array+left+i*5, 5);`.

The parameter passed is the array address which changes according to the value of i. How can I modify this code so that it works in Java?The method is as below:

```
public int findMedian(int arr[], int n)
{
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr[n/2]; // Return middle element
}
```

Comment: Misread at first. No, you cannot pass a reference to the value in the array. I would recommend a function taking the array and an offset and applying the offset to accesses within the function.

Comment: Can you show how the method uses the address, and how it is passed?

Comment: I've added the function findMedian.
@mascoj: Offset as in the index?

Comment: This is confusing, other than that you don't need to pass the size separately in Java, why is your implementation not good enough?

Comment: I need to pass the size as the code is from C++ and the array.length is still holding the original array's size. I need to modify my array to hold 5 elements each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the other overload of `Arrays.sort` to sort only part of the array:

```
public static int findMedian(int arr[], int from, int n) {
    Arrays.sort(arr, from, from + n);
    return arr[from + (n / 2)]; // Return middle element
}
```

Then call like:

```
findMedian(array, left + i * 5, 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, Java doesn't let you perform math on pointers, or really look at them at all. In general, in Java, pointers and memory are the compiler's problem, not yours.

That being said, you should still be able to look over the values in an array; just pass it a reference to the array itself, and then do whatever computations are necessary on the indices. Tough to get more specific without knowing exactly what that method does.

Comment: The method is trying to modify only a part of the array and not the entire array.

Comment: @Tehreem Okay, that's no problem. You pass the method the array, and the information about what part you're modifying. (Doing it that way requires you to change the method header. If that isn't an option at all, you can do something ugly where you make new arrays consisting of the parts to be modified and the parts to stay the same, pass the parts to be modified, and then re-join them. I don't recommend doing that.)

Answer (score 2):

In java is not possible to address directly memory locations.

In C memory is addressed with a pointer.

In java memory is addressed with a reference.

For a comparison between java and C see this [link from Princeton University](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/c2java.html).

Comment: If i want to modify only a part of the array then what should I use? If I don't want to copy it into an other array?

Comment: if you like to modify a single element of the array use the command array[4] = newValue;

Comment: The method is trying to modify only a part of the array and not the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this workable?

```
findMedian(array, left+i*5, 5);
```

Signature:

```
public int findMedian(int[] array, int offset, int value1) {
    //...
}
```